# ScrollIntoView breaks the overflow scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I have a nested child container and when I'm trying to `scrollIntoView` it breaks the parent container. I'm not able to understand why it's acting like this. Please help me out in this.
Please have a look at the code below or on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytj3sLzc/)

```js
function moveToTop() {
  console.log('MOVE TO TOP::');
  const child = document.getElementById('child');
  child.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#child {
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  PARENT
  <div id="something">Something</div>
  <div id="scroller">
    CHILD
    <div id="child">
      GRAND CHILD
      <button onclick="moveToTop()">Top</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What means - "it breaks the parent container"?

Comment: It means when you fire a `scrollIntoView` event the scroll breaks into parent view although the overflow was in child. If you see jsfiddle you can get a better idea about what I'm trying to say. I'm sorry for the bad english.

Comment: But I don't see any problem in your code. `scrollIntoView` works like that - scrolls to the top of the specified item. Everything is correct. What general behavior do you want to see?

Comment: So we have a *Parent*, *Child* and *Grand Child*. When you click on the button, it breaks into the *Parent*. It should go to the top of *Grand Child* only.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. The parent block hides at the top of the window after scrolling - https://ibb.co/fSjKV3p. So?

Comment: my point is how do I make the scroll to top of *Grand Child* only and not *Parent*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228001/discussion-between-mkamranhamid-and-s-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole problem is that `scrollIntoView()` is moving the **window**. But since the `#parent` overflow is hidden, when the window is moved, this element itself breaks. I could suggest setting a `position: fixed` for the `#parent`, which will solve your problem, but it can harm the *layout* in general.

Use the `scroll()` method. The scrolling mechanism itself is:

```
scroller.scroll(0, child.offsetTop - 55);
```

**child.offsetTop** - top element;

**55** - distance from the top of the `#parent` to the top `#scroller`.

The transition animation must be set to css, in selector `#scroller`. Like that:

```
#scroller {
  ...
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```js
function moveToTop() {
  console.log('MOVE TO TOP::');
  const child = document.getElementById('child');
  const scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
  scroller.scroll(0, child.offsetTop - 55);
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#scroller {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#child {
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  left: 20%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  PARENT
  <div id="something">Something</div>
  <div id="scroller">
    CHILD
    <div id="child">
      GRAND CHILD
      <button onclick="moveToTop()">Top</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```