# Why doesn't `ScrollIntoView` work on two simultaneous elements?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have two overflowing elements on the page, I would like to call `ScrollIntoView` at the same time for child elements within both of them.

The following works in Firefox, but not Chrome. Is this a bug?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const two = document.querySelector('.two');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    one.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center', behavior: 'smooth' });
    two.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center', behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
}

#container > div {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1 class="one">Boo!</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1 class="two">Boo!</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<button>click to scroll</button>
```

Comment: I gave you the solution using `scrollTo()`. Do you have any questions or requests? Is there anything that needs to be done in my code? And try to avoid using ScrollIntoView. Since there are disadvantages. For instance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65953805/scrollintoview-breaks-the-overflow-scroll/65955689#65955689

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use the normal `scrollTo()` scrolling method with **smooth scroll**.

I had to use a `for {}`, since I was referring to a collection of scrollable divs inside `#container`:

```
const container_div = document.querySelectorAll("#container > div");
```

Also, I have specified the same class for both `<h1>` control tags:

```
const text = document.querySelectorAll(".boo");
```

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const container_div = document.querySelectorAll("#container > div");
const text = document.querySelectorAll(".boo");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (i = 0; i < container_div.length; i++) {
        container_div[i].scrollTo({ top: text[i].offsetTop, behavior: "smooth" });
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
}

#container > div {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1 class="boo">Boo!</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1 class="boo">Boo!</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<button>click to scroll</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like Chrome blocks 2 smooths scrolls at the same time. Change *behavior* into *auto* and scroll will work.

Comment: Thank you, that's a shame, as I want the smooth scroll. I'll go the library route.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting different timeouts.
In my example i had two components. Each firing at 500 and 1000 ms.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  scrollToCard(this.selectedId);
}, this.type === 'first' ? 500 : 1000);

scrollToCard(id: string) {
  const selected = document.getElementById(
    'scrollTo-' + id + '-' + this.type
  );

  if (selected) {
    selected.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'nearest',
      inline: 'start',
    });
  }
}
```